# sending a string value contains & character to controller ActionMethod in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdown list in my form, when the user changes the dropdown list I want to send  2 values from the view to the controller action method from the url. I did the way using the below method:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () { $('#CountryId').change(function () 
 { 
 window.parent.location.href = "CountryCategory?countryId=" + $('#CountryId').val(); });       });
 </script>
```

This is working fine but in one case I need to send a string value 'M&M' to continentId for the actionmethod and here I'm facing the issue, the variable continentId is taking only one value M and its omitting the part from &.

```
 public actionresult CountryCategory(string countryId,string continentId)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function to encode the string before sending it.

```
var country=$('#CountryId').val();
country=encodeURIComponent(country);
var continentId=encodeURIComponent("Some value here");
window.parent.location.href = "CountryCategory?countryId=" 
                                          + country+"&continentId="+continentId;
```